# How to get user other data when they login in with thier username?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm a newbie in programming. I want to ask is there any way I can get user's data from MySQL in another page when they login in only with their username and password. What I'm facing is

1. I have a login page and main page
2. I have a user database that include user id, username, password and role_id

When the user login, I can get their username thru $SESSION, but what I really want is their role_id so I can use it as a condition to limit the user. Like Admin can get a header bar that has more button and function.

But when I tried to use sql query, it only shows table instead a single text that I can use. Any idea?

main page.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','mes');
$sql = "SELECT role_id from users where username = $user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result;

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

// condition to limit the user
if( (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) && ($result === '202000') ){
    include_once "premierHeader.php";
}
    else{
      include_once "header.php";
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT role_id from users where username = $user";` sql injection waiting to happen

Comment: `query` returns a result object, not a string. You need to `fetch`. Also parameterize your query. That SQL won't work as is, and since you dont check for errors you dont know that yet. Also where is `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` being set, and is a password not required for your login?

Comment: The  `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` is being set in the login page, password is required there also.

Comment: Any update to this issue? Was it solved? Did the answer suffice? If yes, kindly accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING** as some people have already pointed out in the comment section, you're wide open to SQL injections (SQLI Attacks). I highly suggest you make use of parametized, prepared statements using either mysqli or PDO.

With that out of the way, I will be using mysqli prepared statements for my answer specifically.

What you need to understand is that when you get the result of your query, you will be given an object. To actually get a value, you will need to `fetch();` it.

Example:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Username variable via session
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

// DB variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mes";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Declare the query
$sql = "SELECT role_id from users where username = ?";

// Prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// Bind result variable and fetch value
$stmt->bind_result($role_id);
$stmt->fetch();

// Close connection
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

// Optionally, you can put the role id into a session variable
$_SESSION["role_id"] = $role_id;
?>
```

Comment: so you mean like someone can hack my sql thru their input so I need to change to this structure? I read some of it, but I'm bit confused on whether the PDO is suitable for my php code and sql database? or I have to use the mysqli ?

Comment: Yes, if you do not make use of parametized, prepared statements, people can inject malicious queries into your database and do all sorts of things. Rather prevent that. Whether you choose to go with mysqli or PDO is entirely up to you. It's purely preference. I prefer mysqli personally, which is why I used that for my answer.